# SSRS sum based on not-null condition

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I have a report I am building that I am summing a column with the total minutes listed in it then dividing it by 60 to get number of hours like so.

```
=Sum(Fields!designtimeValue.Value) / 60
```

But I have a condition where I want to weed out rows that contain other data in another column

Its laid out like so

```
Submittal_date   Submittal_returned   Design_Hours
   12/01/2014                             180
   12/01/2014        12/02/2014           240
   12/01/2014                             60
```

So I want to do something like `=Sum(IIF(Fields!sumbittal_returned.Value="NULL",Fields!design_hours.Value)) / 60`

But it is throwing an error the sum iff does not allow that number of exceptions

I then need to take it a step further  And be able to take the sum of design total if submittal_returned = NULL total then for any instance submittal_returned = Not-NULL add 120 minutes

Thanks

Edit : format code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIF takes 3 arguments.   A condition, a true result, and a false result.  You have to supply all three.

This would be the correct syntax:

```
=Sum(IIF(IsNothing(Fields!submittal_returned.Value),Fields!design_hours.Value,0)) / 60
```

Although that condition will only be true if submittal_returned actually contained the string "NULL".   If it's actually NULL (not a string), you would need test with the IsNothing() function.

Not sure I understand your last sentence, maybe you mean this?:

```
=Sum(IIF(IsNothing(Fields!submittal_returned.Value),Fields!design_hours.Value,Fields!design_hours.Value + 120)) / 60
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The field is not NULL so I will have to use IsNothing.  And correct on the second part. If say I have two rows that have sumbittal_returned not-null I want it to add 120 minutes to total design time.